# Regex for array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

How do I remove non-numerical characters from a filter in Google Sheets?

I have a function that spits out matching phone numbers into up to 3 subsequent columns. I would like to eliminate non-number characters and a prevailing 1 if there is one, possibly using Regex.

```
=array_constrain(transpose(filter(People!H:H,People!B:B=A10)),1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\D+|^1", "")))
```

[image: 0]